# Random numbers, random colour loops

Tags: javascript, html, loops, random

I'm currently teaching myself HTML/Javascript, with a few challenges set by a colleague.

I'm trying to create loops which will display 3 random numbers between 1-99. Each displaying a random colour. Have done some searching and unable to find anything that incorporates these four aspects of my loop.

Below is where I've got to so far. Any ideas how to convert this into loops?

Many thanks
Chris

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<center>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<h2>10 Random Coloured Numbers</h2>

<p id="no1"></p>
<p id="no2"></p>
<p id="no3"></p>


<script>
document.getElementById("no1","no2","no3").innerHTML =
Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)
document.getElementById("no1","no2","no3").style.color =
'#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);
</script>
```

Comment: Start here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp (etc.) My advice would be to write out, in English, what you want this code to do. This sort of pseudo-code will help you figure out where the peices go and then you can get the syntax right as you figure it out.

Comment: reference doc is MDN, avoid w3schools whenever possible

Comment: The relevant docs from MDN: [Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration), [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementById` only accepts one parameter, so even if you pass three it will only care about the first one, so you should change your code to something like:

```
document.getElementById("no1").innerHTML =
Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)
document.getElementById("no1").style.color =
'#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);
document.getElementById("no2").innerHTML =
Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)
document.getElementById("no2").style.color =
'#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);
document.getElementById("no3").innerHTML =
Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)
document.getElementById("no3").style.color =
'#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);
```

```js
document.getElementById("no1").innerHTML =
Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)
document.getElementById("no1").style.color =
'#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);
document.getElementById("no2").innerHTML =
Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)
document.getElementById("no2").style.color =
'#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);
document.getElementById("no3").innerHTML =
Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)
document.getElementById("no3").style.color =
'#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);
```

```html
<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<h2>10 Random Coloured Numbers</h2>

<p id="no1"></p>
<p id="no2"></p>
<p id="no3"></p>
```

*Also available here: https://jsfiddle.net/9vg262w5/*

Of course it would be repeating your code. Written like that, it's easy to figure out everything is the same except for the `id`, so you could use a `for` and save some code, like this:

```
for(var i=1; i<=3; i++){
  document.getElementById("no"+i).innerHTML =
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)
  document.getElementById("no"+i).style.color =
  '#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);
}
```

```js
for(var i=1; i<=3; i++){
  document.getElementById("no"+i).innerHTML =
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)
  document.getElementById("no"+i).style.color =
    '#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<h2>10 Random Coloured Numbers</h2>

<p id="no1"></p>
<p id="no2"></p>
<p id="no3"></p>
```

*Also available here: https://jsfiddle.net/9vg262w5/1/*

Answer (score 0):

You’re giving `document.getElementById` three arguments, but it can only take one. You were hoping that it would loop through the three IDs for you, but it doesn’t – you’ll have to do the looping yourself.

```js
// fails because getElementById only takes one argument
document.getElementById("no1","no2","no3")

// works (gets one element)
document.getElementById("no1")
```

The first step to using a loop is knowing that passing a variable instead of a literal string will work too:

```js
var firstId = "no1"
// works (gets one element)
document.getElementById(firstId)
```

The other thing you have to know is how to write a loop. There are a few ways to write loops in JavaScript, including `while` and `for` in general, and more advanced but shorter methods such as `.forEach` and `.reduce`.

In this case I would recommend a loop that counts up the numbers from 1 to 3. (That's not actually the simplest method given that you have three strings like `"no1"` that you are looping through, but it makes it easier to later switch to dynamically adding the colors to the page without having to manually write three `p` elements beforehand.) For this numeric loop you would use a `for` loop:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  // this will be run three times, in which
  // the variable i will be 1, 2, or 3
}
```

The things that you have to decide when writing a numeric `for` loop are usually just the variable name `i`, the starting number `1`, and ending number `3`, and when you stop at `<=` or before `<` the ending number. Another common way of looping three times would be with the numbers 0 to 2, with `var i = 0; i < 3; i++`.

For your example code you have IDs formatted like "no1", and you need to get there from the number `1` stored in the variable `i`. For that you can do `var id = "no" + i`.

So now you have this loop:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  var id = "no" + i
  // the variable id will be "no1", "no2", or "no3"
}
```

To help you learn, I won’t write out the final code. But from here it should be easy to figure out what to do by putting together what I’ve told you.

Comment: Really useful thank you. Great to be a part of the StackOverflow community